# get-adgroupmember - Failing when group has member from a different domain.

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

For example. I'm on domainA.local. I run this command.

```
get-adgroupmember -Identity groupA
```

If there is any member of the group that belongs to another domain (domainB\user, etc...) then it fails with this message.

```
get-adgroupmember : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about
the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the
<serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or
turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-adgroupmember -Identity groupA
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (groupA:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more informa
   tion about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from
  the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the cl
 ient, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace lo
gs.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Any ideas on how to get around that? As a workaround today, I only had one user that was in the group that was from another domain so I just removed them, ran my script and then put them back. So I'm pretty positive that it's failing for that reason. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Search the global catalog: `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity groupA -Server dc01.domain.tld:3269` (or 3268)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen unfortunately that didn't work either. I guess I'll have to go back to the vbscript that we were using.

Answer (score 3):

If they're in a different domain, and you have permissions to that domain, try using a try/catch loop, like the example below.  With a try/catch, you tell PowerShell to try{block of code} and if there is an error, don't kill the script, but instead, catch{} and run another block of code instead.

```
$DomainBCreds = get-credential
  try {get-adgroupmember -Identity groupA -ErrorAction Stop}
catch {Get-AdGroupMember -Identity GroupA -Credential DomainB}
```

Alternatively, if you just want the command to keep running, even if there is an error, then you could run Get-ADGroupMember ... -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue, but that is not a best practice.

Comment: Tried that earlier and it gave an error indicating that domainB doesn't have   a group named groupA.    groupA is part of domainA, it just that it has a member(user) that belongs to domainB.

Comment: Is there not a trust between the two domains?  I'm not sure why you'd have an error just running this command of Get-AdGroupMember.  Is the code actualy failing here?

Comment: Yes, there is a trust setup between the domains, which is why groupA, that belongs to domainA, is able to have members(users) from domainB. It definitely fails there. Can take just that one command and run it against a single group and it will fail. If I remove the user from domainB from the group it runs fine, put it back and it fails.

Answer (score 1):

**If the members of the group are on different Domains**, this should work as long as there is a trust relationship between the Domains. As you may note, this is not using `Get-ADGroupMember` but `Get-ADObject` instead.

```
$Group = 'someGroupHere'
$membership = Get-ADGroup $Group -Properties Member
$membership.Member | Group-Object { ($_ -split '(?=DC=)',2)[1] } |
ForEach-Object {
    [adsi] $ldap = 'LDAP://{0}' -f $_.Name
    [string] $domain = $ldap.Name

    foreach($member in $_.Group) {
        $obj = Get-ADObject $member -Server $domain
        [pscustomobject]@{
            MemberOf       = $membership.Name
            Domain         = $domain
            SamAccountName = $obj.SamAccountName
            ObjectClass    = $obj.ObjectClass
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was a better answer to this.  I'm having this exact problem now.  The command doesn't stop running when this error occurs, it continues, but you don't get results for any groups that have accounts from domain B.